# How to flip text vertically/horizontally using php?

Tags: php, text, image-processing, gd, flip

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming from your tags that you mean to flip a GD image.

Do you mean flip as in rotate? That can be done using [**`imagerotate`**](http://de.php.net/imagerotate):

> Rotates the image  image using the given angle  in degrees.
>
> The center of rotation is the center of the image, and the rotated image may have different dimensions than the original image.

Or do you mean **mirror** an image? There's no method for that out of the box, but maybe [**this**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php#54155) code snippet helps. (It not very performant, though, because it copies pixel by pixel.)

For fast advanced image editing operations, [**ImageMagick**](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) is the best tool around. If you are on shared hosting, it needs to be installed by your provider to work.

Comment: Thanks. My solution of this problem in three steps: 1. flip (mirror) image; 2. write text; 3. flip image again;

ImageMagick is very powerful tool, but can't find easier way isung it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some kind of font-substitution trickery like [here](http://www.en.fliptext.net/), or you can use the PHP version of [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org).

Answer (score 1):

Untested... but this seems like it ought to work, composed of other gd functions (maybe slowly):

```
function flipImageHorizontal($im){
  $width = imagesx($im);
  $height = imagesy($im);

  for($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++){          // for each column
    for($x = 0; $x < ($width >> 1); $x++){  // for half the pixels in the row       

       // get the color on the left side
       $rgb = imagecolorat($im, $x, $y);
       $colors = imagecolorsforindex($im, $rgb);
       $current_color = imagecolorallocate($im, $colors["red"], $colors["green"], $colors["blue"]);

       // get the color on the right side (mirror)
       $rgb = imagecolorat($im, $width - $x, $y);
       $colors = imagecolorsforindex($im, $rgb);
       $mirror_color = imagecolorallocate($im, $colors["red"], $colors["green"], $colors["blue"]);

       // swap the colors
       imagesetpixel($im, $x, $y, $mirror_color);        
       imagesetpixel($im, $width - $x, $y, $color);         
    }
  }
}

function flipImageVertical($im){
  $width = imagesx($im);
  $height = imagesy($im);

  for($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++){           // for each row
    for($y = 0; $y < ($height >> 1); $y++){ // for half the pixels in the col

       // get the color on the top
       $rgb = imagecolorat($im, $x, $y);
       $colors = imagecolorsforindex($im, $rgb);
       $current_color = imagecolorallocate($im, $colors["red"], $colors["green"], $colors["blue"]);

       // get the color on the bottom (mirror)
       $rgb = imagecolorat($im, $x, $height - $y);
       $colors = imagecolorsforindex($im, $rgb);
       $mirror_color = imagecolorallocate($im, $colors["red"], $colors["green"], $colors["blue"]);

       // swap the colors
       imagesetpixel($im, $x, $y, $mirror_color);        
       imagesetpixel($im, $x, $height - $y, $color);         
    }
  }
}
```

So you could use `bool imagestring ( resource $image , int $font , int $x , int $y , string $string , int $color )` to create an image from a text string, then run it through the appropriate flip function that I've written above...

Comment: good for whole image flipping, but my goal is rotate only text :)

Comment: @Anatoliy, you mean you want to identify text in an image and horizontally/vertically mirror it? Or do you want to overlay mirrirored text onto an existing image?

Comment: yep, I need to write mirrired text onto an existing image. Thanks for your participation, already found solution: flip image area where text is placed, than write text onto this area, then flip image area back again.

Answer (score 1):

To add vertical text to an existing image in PHP, use function

```
imagettftext($im, 10, $angle, $x, $y, $black, $font, $text);
```

With $angle = 90, the text will be vertical.

Example:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php#refsect1-function.imagettfbbox-returnvalues

Hint:

The example uses $angle = 45, so text is diagonal on the image

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something as simple as this?

```
function toVertical ($string)
{

   foreach (str_split($string) as $letter)
   {
       $newStr.="$letter\n";
   }
   return $newStr;
}


function toHorizontal($string)
{
   foreach(explode("\n",$string) as $letter)
   {
        $newStr.=$letter;
   }
   return $newStr;
}

$v = toVertical("This string should be printed vertically");
echo $v;
$h = toHorizontal($v);
echo $h;


---------- PHP Execute ----------
T
h
i
s

s
t
r
i
n
g

s
h
o
u
l
d

b
e

p
r
i
n
t
e
d

v
e
r
t
i
c
a
l
l
y
This string should be printed vertically
Output completed (0 sec consumed)
```